# 301 redirect not working via .htaccess within WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to apply two 301 re-directs in my .htaccess file within WordPress, but I get a 404 error.

Here's what I have:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# X-XSS-Protection
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>

# X-Frame-Options
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
</IfModule>

# Security Headers - X-Content-Type: nosniff
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>

# BEGIN 301 Redirects
Redirect 301 /old-page-name/ https://www.myurl.com/new-page-name/
Redirect 301 /another-old-page/ https://www.myurl.com/another-new-page/
# END 301 Redirects
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've also tried putting the re-direct info above the WordPress settings.

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule ^old-page-name/ https://www.myurl.com/new-page-name/ [L,R=301]` below `RewriteBase /` line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ordering of rules and mixing of `mod_rewrite` rules with `mod_alias` (`Redirect` directive) will cause problems.

Have your rules like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^old-page-name(/.*)?$ https://www.myurl.com/new-page-name/ [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^another-old-page(/.*)?$ https://www.myurl.com/another-new-page/ [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: This hasn't worked. I've tried flushing the permalinks and clearing my cache. Still getting a 404.

Comment: I've also just discovered that resetting the permalinks via WordPress clears the changes you suggested adding.

Comment: This rule should work if placed in your site root .htaccess (not in any sub-directory). I've tested it on my WP install and `https://www.myurl.com/old-page-name/` does get redirected to new URL. Permalink reset must not overwrite main default WP .htaccess. In fact no WP plugin must overwrite your main .htaccess

Comment: I've tried it again this morning and appears to work! Very strange. It doesn't work without the forward slash e.g. /old-page-name not /old-page-name/. Does this mean I should add the variants?

Comment: I've made changes to make it work with or without trailing `/`