# rewriting url in .htaccess with a wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

i want to change these urls on a site called https://greennutritionguides.dk. I have found out that this can be done via a rewrite in a .htaccess file. However so far i have been unsuccesful with what i have found here on stack, and other sites.

I want these urls changed:

greennutritionguides.dk/shop-4/ to greennutritionguides.dk/shop

and greennutritionguides.dk/services-2/ to greennutritionguides.dk/service

greennutritionguides.dk/member-receipes-2/ to greennutritionguides.dk/opskrifter

this site is a wordpress site and has a .htaccess file that looks like this:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
#<IfModule mod_expires.c>
#ExpiresActive On
#ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
#ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
#ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
#ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
#ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
#ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
#ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
#ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
#ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
#ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
#ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
#</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule    ^shop-4/$    shop   

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /gdk/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /gdk/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code in start of your `.htaccess` before everything else

```
Redirect 301 https://greennutritionguides.dk/shop-4/ https://greennutritionguides.dk/shop
Redirect 301 https://greennutritionguides.dk/services-2/ https://greennutritionguides.dk/service
Redirect 301 https://greennutritionguides.dk/member-receipes-2/ https://greennutritionguides.dk/opskrifter
```

Comment: I have tried with the code you provided, and even if i place it before everything else, nothing happens sadly. it still uses the same urls.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow steps for redirecting URLs

**Step-1:** Take backup of your .htaccess file

**Step-2:** Replace your entire .htaccess file with following code and save it.

```
#BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^shop-4(/.*)?$ https://greennutritionguides.dk/shop/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^services-2(/.*)?$ https://greennutritionguides.dk/service/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^member-receipes-2(/.*)?$ https://greennutritionguides.dk/opskrifter [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteBase /gdk/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /gdk/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
#END WordPress
```

**Step-3:** Clear cache of your browser and then check it.

You can refer [301 redirect not working via .htaccess within WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489570/301-redirect-not-working-via-htaccess-within-wordpress) as well

Comment: Thanks for trying to help :) however this does not work either i get the following message:

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: Are you using "RewriteRule . /index.php [L]" OR RewriteRule . /gdk/index.php [L]? Please let me know, so based on that, I can suggest a solution

Comment: Not sure if you mean on the one i currently have, but as you can see in my original code, i have 

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule . /gdk/index.php [L]

Im assuming you mean the last one :)